# After reverting to Windows 7, Visual Studio and IIS were broken

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

It's taken me two days of debugging to fix this, so I thought I would share it with anyone having the same problem.

I decided to upgrade my Win7 Pro development system to Win 10, and discovered that various important stuff didn't work, so decided to revert back to Win 7 Pro.  Most stuff started working again, but Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate could not debug web applications.  I didn't save the exact error message but it came from global.asax and was something like "Parser error message: Cannot load type 'myclass.MvcApplication'"  It was basically the same for Forms projects.

I rebuilt the project, tried various fixes that I found here and other places like moving to /bin, but nothing worked.  Fortunately I have another system with VS, and by sharing the disk was able to create a working project on that disk with the other system, and then see it fail with my development system, so I knew that the compile and code was ok.  Then I tried running just with IIS, no VS, and when it failed too that told me that it wasn't really VS, it was deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The fix ended up being to remove all of the .NET Frameworks that I had installed at various times, and repairing the VS install.  Now things work, and I hope that I can save someone else from going through this.  If not the actual fix, then hopefully the method will help.

Comment: One more thing.  After the VS repair I tried running again with just IIS, and discovered that the app pool had reverted to .NET 2.0, so it didn't work.  Changing the app pool to 4.0 fixed it.